# FFmpeg first frame byte size over 2x size compared to all other frames - w/ 100% keyframes

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, mpeg-dash

I'm encoding an h264 mp4 and am having a small issue with the output byte size of the first frame vs. all other frames. There's no frame duplication happening, rather just that the first frame always ends up being ~2x the byte size of other frames. My use-case requires that the first frame be very similar in size compared to other frame.

Here are the ffmpeg encoding parameters:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i "C:\Test%4d.jpg" -c:v libx264 -g 1 -vf "scale=3840:2160" -crf 19 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\Test.mp4
```

And the frame details using ffprobe:

```
ffprobe C:\Test.mp4 -show_frames -of compact -show_entries frame=pict_type,pkt_size

ffprobe version N-79143-g8ff0f6a Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 30.100 / 57. 30.100
  libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\users\dusti\downloads\Test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.29.101
  Duration: 00:00:00.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 240225 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x2160 [SAR 9:16 DAR 1:1], 240662 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
frame|pkt_size=1377043|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=406953|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=407200|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=406647|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=405276|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=404715|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=403226|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=401806|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=400750|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=400189|pict_type=I
```

I've confirmed that it's not just a reporting issue with ffprobe by converting the file with mp4box:

```
mp4box.exe -dash 16.666 -frag 16.666 -rap c:\Test.mp4
```

Which returns an MPD file:

```
<Initialization range="0-922"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="923-1378146" indexRange="923-966"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="1378147-1785280" indexRange="1378147-1378190"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="1785281-2192661" indexRange="1785281-1785324"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="2192662-2599489" indexRange="2192662-2192705"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="2599490-3004946" indexRange="2599490-2599533"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="3004947-3409842" indexRange="3004947-3004990"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="3409843-3813249" indexRange="3409843-3409886"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="3813250-4215236" indexRange="3813250-3813293"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="4215237-4616167" indexRange="4215237-4215280"/>
      <SegmentURL mediaRange="4616168-5016537" indexRange="4616168-4616211"/>
    </SegmentList>
```

I tried encoding a dummy black frame and it does seem to work around the issue but I'd really prefer to not do that. Here are the frame sizes with the first frame replaced by a pure black frame:

```
frame|pkt_size=2173|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=466255|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=430179|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=416652|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=411401|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=407174|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=405377|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=403207|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=401588|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_size=401200|pict_type=I
```

Anyone have any clues on how to control this behavior? I imagine it might have something to do with the CRF quality algorithm but really have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dustin

**Update 7/22/16**
Upon a little more digging I can see that ffmpeg is using a lower QP for the first frame:

```
[libx264 @ 05380b60] frame=   0 QP=14.92 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:32400 P:0    SKIP:0    size=1485053 bytes
[libx264 @ 05380b60] frame=   1 QP=29.48 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:32400 P:0    SKIP:0    size=361196 bytes
[libx264 @ 05380b60] frame=   2 QP=29.48 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:32400 P:0    SKIP:0    size=359406 bytes
```

But I've still not found a way to avoid this behavior. I tried setting qpmin/qpmax to non-default values but that didn't change anything. Per my comment below, two-pass encoding does not exhibit this behavior. Still looking for a way to use CRF encoding without this large initial frame.

Comment: It seems encoding with two pass VBR does avoid this behavior. Though I would much prefer to use CRF encoding to maintain a constant quality.

Comment: Constant Rate Factor (CRF) will adjust the QP for the frame depending on what is happening in the frame - in very simple terms when there is little action or movement it will lower the QP and throw away more so you get a smaller packet. Its pretty much by definition going to give you a non-constant frame size. Is your experience suggesting that even allowing for this the first frame is abnormally large?

Comment: @Mick, the first and second frames are near identical in content so there should be no reason to have such a difference in QP. Though I certainly could understand this just being a necessary minor bug for the CRF algorithm which shouldn't need to regularly care about that single first frame.

Answer (score 1):

A hack workaround is to split the output i.e. encode the video in CRF mode with the dummy frame up front, and then chop it off i.e.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ss 0.016 -c copy test1.mp4
```

Here the ss value <= `1/framerate`. Since this is an intra-coded stream, this is a precise split.